# Translating math to JavaScript; convergent/divergent series

Tags: javascript, math, series, convergence

I am trying calculate the following series in JavaScript:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
var res = []
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    res.push(i / ((i * Math.sqrt(i + 1)) + ((i + 1) * Math.sqrt(i))))
}
```

But this makes the series *possibly* converge towards 0 rather than approach 1. Here's the first 150 steps:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my translation from math to JavaScript? Maybe my parentheses?

**UPDATE**

As per @Barmar 's answer, the correct code shows convergence to 1 only for small values of infinity, diverging after 4 steps:

[image]

Comment: You're pushing the series into an array, not adding them together.

Comment: What is `index`?

Comment: Sorry removed index. In my original code they were all index.

Comment: If you add up all the array elements, you'll get something approaching 1.

Comment: You aren't doing summation in your JS code.

Comment: If your loop starts at 0, the first term is `0 / 0`, which is `NaN`.

Comment: According to [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+infinity+k+%2F+%28k+*+sqrt%28k+%2B+1%29+%2B+%28k+%2B+1%29+*+sqrt%28k%29%29), the series diverges (which is btw also what i see in javascript). You seem to be plotting individual terms, instead of the sum.

Comment: Oops, yes plotting the individual terms instead of sum. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each element of the series to the previous sum.

You also need to start at `i = 1` to avoid dividing by 0.

```js
console.config({
  maxEntries: Infinity
});

var res = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  sum += i / ((i * Math.sqrt(i + 1)) + ((i + 1) * Math.sqrt(i)));
  res.push(sum);
}
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that this shows that the series doesn't actually converge to 1. Which is also apparent from your incorrect graph, since you can see that the first 5 elements are between `0.195` and `0.293`, and these add up to more than 1.

Comment: Right, the conjecture he's trying to prove is apparently false.

Comment: Every term is positive, so the moment you see a partial sum larger than one, it can't be true.

Comment: Correct, the series hits 1 at 4 steps, then diverges from there.

Comment: In other words, it converges to 1 for small values of infinity.